# Read_html in R shiny app based on user url input

Tags: r, web-scraping, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app where the user can copy and paste a web address as text input, and the app will then read in the web data from the address they provided. I tried using the textinput to let user enter their web address, and then using the read_html function in rvset to read in the web data.

On the ui side I have something like this:

```
 conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.Articlesource == 'Web page'",
        textInput("fileRequest", "Copy and paste link to aritcle here")
      )
    )
```

On the server side:

```
article <- reactive({
if (input$Articlesource == "Web page") {
       read_html(input$fileRequest)      
    } 
})
```

I don't think it reads anything in like this. I just need to read the web data in and then do some further analysis on it. And no, I do not have a specific website I want to use. Basically I want the user to be able to enter whatever they want. Anyone with experience on something like this?

Comment: What makes you believe this doesn't work?

Comment: If you do a simple render or print of the contents in 'article' after this, nothing shows up.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean `article` or `article()`?

Comment: Yes, article().

Comment: I cannot reproduce a bug here. Realize that `xml2::read_html` does not return something that's always printable on the console. For instance, for me, `stuff <- read_html("https://google.com")` captures something without error, but when I try to view it on the console (`stuff` or `print(stuff)`), I see `Error in nchar(desc) : invalid multibyte string, element 2`, indicating either I'm behind in a version or there's a bug. But `as.character(stuff)` works fine. If you have something more concrete that demonstrates how it is failing, that would be useful.